# Change senders name create calendar invites from spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I have a Google Form (on a team drive) as creator of the form and the Spreadsheet. It creates a calendar event and invites some groups of people. 
The sender in the invite mail is Me as owner of the script, sheet and calendar.

I want to be able to change the sender name of the calendar invites to something generic like (support@company.com.
Is it in the script?

```
 masterCal.createAllDayEvent(newEmployee + " börjar på " + company,  
                        new Date(startDate),
                        {location:eventLoca,
                          description:"<b>Bolag:</b>" + " " + company + 
                        "<br><b>Kostnadsställe:</b>"+ " " + costAccount +
                        "<br><b>DOA LEVEL:</b>"+ " " + doaLevel +
                        "<br><b>Ansvarig Chef:</b><br>" + bossMail +
                        "<br><b>Sista anställningsdatum:</b><br>" + endDate + 
                        "<br><br><b>Kopiera rättigheter från:</b><br>" + copyUser + 
                        "<br><br><b>Mobil och abbonnemang:</b><br>" + mobilePhone + 
                        "<br><br><b>Användaren skall ha följande IT-verktyg:</b><br>" + hardware + 
                        "<br><br><b>Kommentarer:</b><br>" + comments 
                        , guests:attendees,sendInvites:true});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Easy solution

If you are the admin of the domain `company.com`, create a new user with the name `support` and write the script from his account. You can select in the [Admin console](https://admin.google.com/Dashboard) which permissions to give to this user.

### Elegant solution

Create a [service account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/understanding-service-accounts) and run the script through this service account or a user impersonated by this service account. [set-up a service account in Apps Script](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the owner of "masterCal" will always be the sender, so if acceptable / doable, you should change your script to use a different "masterCal" calendar, and use one of that "generic" account, assuming that account is tied with a Google Account.

Comment: Sounds logic! Thanks for advice